# Parsing string and assigning specific values to variables

Tags: c#, .net, string

API returns string as follows: `"error=OK\neta=2 - 3 Days\nprice=24.18"`

Besides using substring with `start/stop` index and or splitting everything by delimiter characters and into a word array can I just pick out the value after `"nprice="` and from `"neta="` to (before "\")" straight away ?

Comment: Use RegEx. That will simplify.

Comment: splitting on delimns is pretty straight away ... why isn't that good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `yourString.Split(new[] { @"\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)` to get a list of the substrings.

However, my preference would be to turn this into a dictionary:

```
var yourString = @"error=OK\neta=2 - 3 Days\nprice=24.18";
var lookup = (from sub in yourString.Split(new[] { @"\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
              let parts = sub.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)
              select parts).ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
```

You would then use this like so:

```
 var error = lookup["error"];
 var eta = lookup["eta"];
 var price = Convert.ToDecimal(lookup["price"]);

 Console.WriteLine("Error Code: {0},  ETA: {1},  Price: {2:C}", error, eta, price);
```